# unable to get session value in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have put valuein a session in logincontroller which has redirected to bookappointment controller after inserting data into database.

I tried to access this session in bookappointment blade view but it is not showing any value.

LoginController.php

```
 public function login()
    {

        
       
         $this->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
         ]);

         $customer = Customer::where('email', $this->email)->get();

        
        if($customer->first()) {
            
              Interest::create([

                    'agent_id' => session('pagentid'),
                    'customer_id' => $customer->first()->id,
                    'property_id' => session('propid'),
                ]);
                session()->put('customerid', $customer->first()->id);
               
       session()->flash('message', "Please, choose when you would like to go for inspection");
       return redirect()->route('bookappointment');
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('bookappointment', [BookappointmentController::class, 'create'])->name('bookappointment');
```

BookappointmentController

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.bookappointment',);
    }
```

bookappointment.blade.php

```
`{{session()->get('customerid')}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get() method will retrieve all customer from database. If you want to retrieve the first entry in database, use first() method instead:

```
$customer = Customer::where('email', $this->email)->first();

if($customer) {        
   Interest::create([
     'agent_id' => session('pagentid'),
     'customer_id' => $customer->id,
     'property_id' => session('propid'),
   ]);
   
   session()->put('customerid', $customer->id);
//....
```